# How can i add a wild character on the following piece of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I write the code below so no matter the number that changes (in this case 4280, 4342, 4150, 4870 etc) i could be able to disable the check box?
What i am looking for is a way to substitute the number with a wild character

```js
$("input[name='addon-4280-ga-2\\[\\]']").prop('checked', false);

 $("input[name='addon-4342-ga-2\\[\\]']").prop('checked', false);

 $("input[name='addon-4150-ga-2\\[\\]']").prop('checked', false);

 $("input[name='addon-4870-ga-2\\[\\]']").prop('checked', false);
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the "starts with" and "contains" selector might work for you.

```
$("input[name^='addon-'][name*='-ga-2']").prop("checked", false);
```

For further reference:
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Actually it does not work on this case because it unchecked some other checkbox that should also start with addon and should not be unchecked. ( for example: addon-4342-ing-0)

Comment: You can combine selectors and also use the "ends with" or "contains".